# Select settings set via ComboBox

Tags: c#

I have several mail templates that can be selected via a combo box. For each template I've created a separate settings set under `Properties`.

Now I want to read the corresponding set depending on which template was selected. The name of the template is equal to the name of the settings set. And I can't get any further at this point.

Is there a way to add a placeholder to the call of the set? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
string SelectedTemplate = this.ComboBox_MailTemplates.GetItemText(this.ComboBox_MailTemplates.SelectedItem);
string TemplateParameters = Properties.[SelectedTemplate].Default.Parameter;
MessageBox.Show(TemplateParameters);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with Reflection

```
var settingType = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.BaseType == typeof(System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase) && x.Name == SelectedTemplateName);
var settingTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(settingType);
var parameterItemProperty = settingType.GetProperty("Parameter");
var parameterItemValue = parameterItemProperty.GetValue(settingTypeInstance);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much! I definitely need to get deeper with Reflections.